# IntelliJ output console INFO colour

Tags: intellij-idea, console

Does anyone know why IntelliJ is printing all log messages to my console in red coloured text?  This make it really hard to distinguish between info and trace messages and the actual error messages that I need to see!

[image]

I'm using Tomee and CDI if this is relevant!

Thanks for your assistance,

**Edit**
My setting all look okay within the preferences window:

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have stacked with the same problem too. For now I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.1 and there are no such opportunity to color logs the way you want.
For me I have solved it by using [**Grep Console Plugin**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console/) and recommend it to you. 
It's easy to install and use.

Before
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've been using this plugin for a while now and it's really helpful.

Answer (score 14):

I had exactly same problem. Not sure about your case, but mine was following:

I use [SLF4j Simple Logger](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html) Facade in my projects (because it is simple, yup). So it turned out that if you don't specify `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile` property in `simplelogger.properties` file located in your `resources` folder (as well as if you don't have that file at all), the logger output defaults to `System.err` which is red in Idea.

The solution proposed by @pavlo sort of helped, but the base colour was still red.

So I added this line to `src/java/main/resources/simplelogger.properties`:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out
```

and installed **Grep Console** Plugin. Together they perfectly solve the problem with SLF4j Simple Logger.

Comment: I was doing this, just switched to Logback though and worked immediately. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854797/slf4j-with-simplelogger-is-it-possible-to-log-to-a-file-and-system-out

Comment: But this causes errors to be white as well. Not a good solution I think.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be solved by adding the following VM option to your run configuration.

`-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out`

Comment: Didn't help in my case, though our project is using slf4j. I tried adding it to the Run Configuration by adding to VM Options while debugging a test, but I was still seeing the output in red.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I map the `Console Colors` for `Bad command or filename` to my preferred `Logger.INFO` color, it works fine.
This is an issue that needs fixing, for for now this workaround works for me.

Answer (score 0):

using SLF4J use something like

```
%highlight(%-5level)
```

In your logback.xml pattern to highlight the log level