# Centralized console coloring for Spring Boot project with several modules

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, colors, console

I would like to get colors in my running console of Spring Boot project with **several** **modules** for Intellij IDEA. Like this:

[image]

In ordinary case I can add in *application.properties* line

> spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS

or

> logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]
>   %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n

In my current case I have **several** modules in my project 
[image]

and it is not very convinient to add such lines in *application.properties* in every module so I would like to use some centralized solution (like one plugin to set colors for a IntelliJ console for every application).

Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Add `-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS` in the VM Options of the Template Spring Boot run/debug configuration?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554884/8112217

Comment: @CrazyCoder This is the same as for application.properties - I should add this property to every module VM configuration, right?

Comment: No, if you place it in the Template configuration, all new Run configurations you create will inherit this option automatically.

Comment: O, I'll try it now.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks a lot. This is what I needed.

Comment: Pay attention that after adding this property to VM Option of the Template then every NEW configuration will inherit this option. So I recreate my application configurations after adding a template's VM option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS` in the **Template** Spring Boot run/debug configuration **VM Options**:

[image: template]